# Dualhead2go & Ubuntu. How to separate Monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

The thing I want to achieve is to use two monitors with my MacBook Pro in the middle. I boot into Ubuntu usually. Now I found that Dualhead2go DisplayPort Edition is the best way to go, to add two Displays to my setup.

But Dualhead2go acts like there only is one monitor with 3840x1200 resolution. How do I tell the X Server, that there should be two discrete screens on the big new second display?

I'm using Awesome WM and like to have a setup like:
Left Monitor, MacBook Monitor, Right Monitor
Where Left and Right Monitors is the one big screen connected via Dualhead2go.

Comment: What do you mean with "two dicrete screen"? Do you want a separate X-Session on the second monitor?

Comment: Yes so that I do not have 2 screens (the macbook screen and the wide screen), but three separate screens. It would be cool, if it´s all one X-Session, so I can still move windows from screen to screen.

Comment: Wait, what? Now we're up to three screens...you either have one big monitor or separate X-Sessions...please define: `screen`.

Comment: Okay I want to have 3 monitors (physical, two 1920 widescreen tfts and one macbook 1440 display). Now those two 1920 widescreen tfts are connected via Dualhead2Go, which would appear as one 3840 screen. But I want to have them separated. I'm sorry, English is not my mother tounge, so I might be misleading.

Comment: Your or mine English is not the misleading thing, the misleading thing is the term "separated". You don't want to have one giant desktop, but you don't want separate X-Sessions neither...do you mean that those are used as separate desktops? Like with different Gnome Workspaces?

Comment: Right. I still want to be able to move windows from one display to another. But I do not want to have one big screen.